# Из числа получить массив

Tags: php

Как из числа 720 получить массив содержащий 7 2 0

Comment: Вариантов куча: формируем массив делением числа на 10, преобразуем в текст и в цикле по символам текста формируем массив, через preg_match_all в выводе получаем массив и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$num = strval(720);
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($num); $i++)
    $res[] = (int)$num[$i];
```

Answer (score 5):

1. исходное число преобразовать в строку напр. через [преобразование типов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php);
2. строку разбить в массив строк по символу [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-split.php);
3. каждый цифру преобразовать обратно в число обработав каждый элемент массива через [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) и [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php).

[В одну строку](http://ideone.com/feJ1K8) это так: `array_map('intval', str_split($i))`